# if taking 0 integer value as null

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm using axios to post data to this API in react but it is not entering in the if block even if the server reads those values at the same time when I'm making the exact same request from a rest client its working properly. Here is the code in the react client side

```
const QESAPI = async ()=>{
  let dataAPI = {
    'class_id' :  36,
    'limit' : 10,
    'offset' : 0
  };
  let headers = {
    'x-access-token': sessionStorage.getItem('token'),
    'user_id': sessionStorage.getItem('userId')
  }

  await axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/get/qes`,dataAPI,{
    headers:headers
  }).then(

    res => {
      console.log(dataAPI);
      console.log(headers);
      console.log(res);
    }
  )
    .catch(err=>console.log(err));
}
```

Here is the code server side

```
const getQES = async (req, res) => {
    const db = req.app.get('db');
    const class_id = req.body.class_id;
    const limit = req.body.limit;
    const offset = req.body.offset;
    console.log(req.body);
    if (class_id && limit && offset) {
        const response = await db.getQES({
            class_id,
            limit,
            offset
        });
        if (!response.empty) {
            res.status(200).end(JSON.stringify(response));
        } else {
            res.status(201).end("Can't get QES");
        }
    } else {
        res.status(201).end(common.try_again);
    }
};
```

Here is the result in the client (chrome console)

```
{data: "Invalid details, please try again", status: 201, statusText: "Created", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {url: "**api location here but I ve hidden it**", method: "post", data: "{"class_id":0,"limit":10,"offset":0}", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), …}
data: "Invalid details, please try again"
headers: {content-length: "33"}
request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
status: 201
statusText: "Created"
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue that I can see in your code is that the condition used at the server side i.e., `class_id && limit && offset`.

As the data being passed to backend from the client side is as below

```
{
    'class_id' :  36,
    'limit' : 10,
    'offset' : 0
}
```

If we observe the `offset` value as `0` which is a falsy value in JS. So, even though the values are being passed from client side and the values are being read but the condition is getting failed because of `offset: 0`.

May be if you expecting numbers also as input then you might have to do the check for `undefined` and `null` explicitly.

```
if((class_id !== undefined || class_id !== null) 
   && (limit !== undefined || limit !== null) 
   && (offset !== undefined || offset !== null)) {
//... code
}
```

Or in a shorter way you can also do like

```
if ((class_id != null) && (limit != null) && (offset != null)) {
//... code
}
```

Comment: I had already solved this by using toString() in front of offset in if condition, because JS takes 0 value of and integer as null so, this is also the way it can be done. Thanks